# Linux file system skeleton version control

Tags: linux, version-control, filesystems

We are doing some embedded Linux project, the vendor provides us a basic filesystem skeleton, and we would like to put it into the version control system (GIT), but there are some special files which GIT does not like, for example, the device file, the pipe files, etc. I wounder if anyone have a better suggestion to put a filesystem under version control? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices;

1) either put the script which creates the nodes in /dev and the like under version control, and have your build system execute that script.

or

2) Make a `dd` of the basic file system to a plain file, and put that dd resulting file under version conntrol

Comment: Don't use dd. Try tar instead, but do test that it restores the files correctly before you depend on it. A third alternative is to use a loopback file system. This is like what happens when you mount a .iso file, but you can also create a normal empty file tree on an ext2fs filesystem that fits in a single small OS file.

Answer (score 1):

There are some script for keeping dev files with git, eg: EtcKeeper http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/